# Lightbox with HTML content, and transparent background

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, transparency, lightbox

Is it possible to use a lightBox plugin, that supports HTML and with transparent background? So that the body is transparent, but the content it self is opaque?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes if you play around the settings and the .css of the plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set "background-color" of the "Body" to "background-color: transparent !important;"